# User view data in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, gridview

I would like to ask your opinions on how the current log in user can view the data that he/her entered. For example, I am building expenses tracking system. Users can insert all the expenses spent by them by select the month ( drop down menu) which I already made and the expenses by insert them in each text boxes. After they've confirmed the items, the system will submit all the data in the database (sql).

How can I retrieve only the row that related to the current username to be shown in gridview of something else> I am working with ASP.NET in C# language.

Comment: OP, to confirm that Andrew and I have made the correct edits to your question, you're using ASP.NET, not classic ASP, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First this is a great tutorial on how SQL and asp.net works together. It explains how to get data from a database and how to update that same data.

http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlparameter

in the first example the sql statment says

```
new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Dogs1 WHERE Name LIKE @Name", connection))
```

Your sqlstatment will say

```
new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [What your table name is] WHERE UserID = @UserName", connection))
```

HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;

on this line replace this

```
 command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Name", dogName));
```

with this
     command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("UserName", HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name));

```
you will then need to pull your infomation out of your datareader
```

Similar to the example above as well. If you need more direction please let me know.

Hope that helps!

Comment: hi. thnks for reply. But i dont really get the idea. Can u pls make it clear?

Comment: Can you give me an idea of your table structure ? also are you using windows auth or forms auth

Comment: Hi micah, I am glad that you reply my comment! Thank you. I have 18 columns of ExpTab. There are 8 columns for expenses type, 8 columns for each expenses price, month column, and username column. When user login their acc, they are enable to view all their records. Only their records. Like on Jan, what expenses their bought, feb, march  and ect. I am using form authentication. I am waiting for your reply. Thank you :)

Comment: added more detail check and see if that helps

Comment: Micah, if i could go to ur place, i'll give u hug!! Thank you :D

Comment: Can i ask one more last question? I dont know how to do like i want user view their expenses by choose month at dropdown menu and all the expenses will be showed at textboxes. I tell u what, im very bad at coding. Like seriously. But u can ignore me if u have enough of me. Anyway thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should detect the user identifier/name/id to get its data. This could be done through **cookie** or **session** .